# Función que retorna otra función

Tags: funciones, clausuras

```
function saludar(saludo){
  return function nombre(){
    return saludo + " " + nombre;
  };
}
const saludarHola = saludar("Hola");
console.log(saludarHola("Bro"));
```

Buenas, estoy tratando de que la respuesta del código sea "Hola Bro" y el resultado es:

```
"Hola function nombre(){
    return saludo + " " + nombre;
  }"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no se cual sea el motivo de hacerlo de esa manera, pero segun observo te falta mandar el para parametro "nombre" dentro de la funcion nombre,algo asi:

```
function nombre(nombre){
    return saludo + " " + nombre;
};
```

y toda la funcion quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```js
function saludar(saludo){
  return function nombre(nombre){
    return saludo + " " + nombre;
  };
}
const saludarHola = saludar("Hola");
console.log(saludarHola("Bro"));
```

Comment: Antes imprimía "Hola function..." porque la variable `nombre` hacía referencia a la función en sí.

Comment: Correcto. Y como se concatenaba con la intro del saludo, implícitamente invoca a `Function.prototype.toString`

Comment: Clarooo.Perfecto, muchas gracias. Es solo un ejercicio de Clousures Erik, por eso lo tengo  que hacer de esa manera.